# Yarn 2 : how to run a script from the `node_modules/.bin` directory?

Tags: yarnpkg

How can I run a script from the `node_modules/.bin` directory with Yarn 2 ?

**Example**

Suppose I need to run an "eslint" script located in that directory

```
node_modules
├── .bin
│   ├── eslint
```

With NPM, I can just run `npx eslint` to run the excutable. How can I achieve this with Yarn 2 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is same as what it used to be in classic Yarn, run this:

```sh
yarn eslint
```

Refer: https://yarnpkg.com/cli/run#details

> This command will run a tool. The exact tool that will be executed will depend on the current state of your workspace:
>
> - If the scripts field from your local package.json contains a matching script name, its definition will get executed.
> - **Otherwise, if one of the local workspace's dependencies exposes a binary with a matching name, this binary will get executed.**
> - Otherwise, if the specified name contains a colon character and if one of the workspaces in the project contains exactly one script with a matching name, then this script will get executed.

If you want to ignore any user defined scripts and only check for binaries, you can pass [`-B` option](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/run#options-B%2C-binaries-only).

---

There is also [`yarn exec`](https://yarnpkg.com/cli/exec):

```sh
yarn exec eslint
```

Comment: This command is not suitable. Scripts in the package.json will take precedence in case of name collision. And the binaries mentioned in the second list item are not the ones located in `node_modules/.bin`

Comment: @Backslash36 what about `yarn exec eslint` instead? BTW, in `yarn run` you can pass `-B` to _ignore any user defined scripts and only check for binaries_.

Comment: `yarn exec` does the trick ! I wish the docs were clearer on the fact that node_modules binaries can be accessed globally with this command.